# how to differentiate excel sessions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel 2010, one excel session is a window, wherein it can open multiple spreadsheets in the same Excel 2010 window.

However, this feature is not available in Excel 2016 and was discontinued since Excel 2013.

During our computation, it's important to differentiate different excel sessions such that --

- data in memory (we built plug-ins which maintain data in memory) will
  be separated for different session
- one session's crash won't affect other sessions.

how to do that in excel 2016?

explanation: I understand that I could have multiple sessions opening multiple excel documents, e.g

- session A, opening A1.xlsx and A2.xlsm
- session B, opening B1.xlsx and B2.xlsm

In Office 2010, this will be shown as 2 windows, one for session A and one for session B, then in window 1 for sesssion A, there are two documents opened, namely A1 and A2, similar to session B's window 2.

Now in Offcie 2016, all files, A1, A2, B1, B2 are in a different window, I can't differentiate which belongs to the same session.

I don't want to use 4 sessions to open the 4 files, as some excel files need stay in the same session to exchange data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer the first part of your question (how to have multiple sessions in Excel 2013/2016):**

You need to follow the instructions as pointed out by [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3165211/how-to-force-excel-to-open-in-a-new-instance-by-default):

1. Exit all instances of Excel.
2. Start Registry Editor:

   - In Windows 10, click Start, type regedit in the Search box, and then select regedit.exe in the search results.
   - In Windows 8 or Windows 8.1, move the pointer to the upper-right corner, select Search, enter regedit in the search box, and then select regedit.exe in the search results.
3. Locate and select the following registry subkey:

   `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options`
4. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then select DWORD Value.
5. Enter `DisableMergeInstance`, and then press Enter.
6. In the Details pane, press and hold (or right-click) `DisableMergeInstance`, and then select Modify.
7. In the Value data box, enter `1`, and then click OK.

**To answer the second part of your question (how to identify sheets that are in the same session):**

As far as I know it is not possible to show two Excel sheets as "subwindows" in the same window, like it used to be in older versions of Excel. However, what you can do is on the "View" ribbon, you can click the "Switch Windows" button and it will list you all the windows (and only those) of that Excel session.

If you use "Open" from within an existing Excel window, the file will be opened in that same session.

Comment: this is not for my question, allow me update the question more clearly.

Comment: I have update my answer to your updated question.